# Display specific value in Flatlist React native

Tags: arrays, react-native, render, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to diplay a specific value from the render method in flatlist but when i use {item.Name[0]} it shows me all the first letters from all the Name values but i want the whole first Name.

````
 return (
    
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <FlatList 
      horizontal
      data={this.state.data}
      renderItem={({ item,index }) => (
        <View style={styles.card_template}  >
      
      <View style={styles.text_container}>
        <Text style={styles.card_title}>{item.Name[1]}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.card_subtitle}>{item.Phone} </Text>
      </View>
      
    </View>
      )}
    />
  </View>
    
   );
  }
}```
````

Comment: You should just type item.Name

Comment: if I type item.Name it shows me all the values but i only need the second one

Comment: Can you share the json object and specify what you wanna show?

Comment: { "Latitude": 40.61266600649516, "Longitude": 22.963778225752637, "Name": "Polis Park",  "Price": 2.5}
{ "Latitude": 40.61414327729985, "Longitude": 22.963899703209353, "Name": "City Parking - Plakantonakis",  "Price": 2.5}
 { "Latitude": 40.61003941312086, "Longitude": 22.964775765699134, "Name": "LUXURY PARK", "Price": 2.5}
 { "Latitude": 40.6092271241841, "Longitude": 22.962089417863957, "Name": "ParkPoint",  "Price":0}
 { "Latitude": 40.62711918641922, "Longitude": 22.951806518041334, "Name": "Thessbike Central Parking",  "Price": 4 } 
Thats the data when i console.log(item)

Comment: i take the data from firebase

Comment: What do you want to show in the list? if you want list to show "Polis Park", "City Parking -Plakantonakis", "ParkPoint"   then you should write {item.Name}. What do you really want to show?

Comment: Get rid of FlatList completely then. Instead of it, just write `<Text>{this.state.data[1].Name}</Text>`

Comment: I can not do that. To be more specific I'm making a parking app. I want to show when user clicks on the parking icon a flatlist display but the problem is that is not starting from the clicked parking but from the first one. That's why is I can access a specific item the flatlist can starts from there. I do not know if there is another way.

Comment: Then you need to be more clear about it. So you want the list to show Polis Park first because user clicked it?  And then you wanna show the other items other than Polis Park?

Comment: Yes exactly that!

Comment: Next question is how do you know the user clicked Polis Park? Will it be always the second item on your list? Do you have any props from another screen or component where you hold any data about it?

Comment: dataMarkers= () => {
  return this.state.data.map((marker,index) => <Marker onPress= {()=>this.markerClick(marker)}
 
    key={index}
      coordinate={{ latitude: marker.Latitude, 
      longitude: marker.Longitude}}
      title={marker.Name} >
 
  </Marker > )}
//thats how i render all the parkings

markerClick=(marker)=>{
 
  alert(marker.Name)
//and with these i know the exact parking when i pressed it gives me the correct parking

Comment: After the alert on markerClick do this: `var temp = this.state.data.filter(x=> x.Name != marker.Name);  temp.unshift(marker);  this.setState({data:temp});`

And on the renderitems just use item.Name

Comment: It actually works!!!Thanks a lot for your time and for your help!! You made my day!!

Comment: It may not be the best way but I'm glad I helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the alert on markerClick do this:

```
var temp = this.state.data.filter(x=> x.Name != marker.Name);  
temp.unshift(marker);  
this.setState({data:temp});
```

And on the renderitems just use `item.Name`

You are moving the selected marker to the first place in the array and selected item will be always on top

Answer (score 0):

I think Problem is resolved if you following solution:

```
<Text style={styles.card_title}>{item.Name}</Text>
```

then try.

Comment: I have tried this and i get  undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item[1].Name')